# Can I make git-flow use normal tags (not annotated tags)?

Tags: git, git-flow

When I finish a release I'm prompted for a commit message, then a message for the tag. I don't put messages in my tags (at least not in my release tags) so I leave it empty. The result is that no tag is created, and I have to create it manually, e.g.:

```
git tag v1.15.3 master
```

#### How can I tell git-flow not to use annotated tags?

---

I'm not interested in working around this by just putting something in the tag message. Annotated tags are for associating information with a tag. Using them in place of normal tags will drive me crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/blob/15aab26490facf285acef56cb5d61025eacb3a69/git-flow-release#L248

```
# git-flow-release - checkout and update this file
# Change lines # 248 in the above file
if ! git_tag_exists "$tagname"; then
    local opts="-a"
```

remove the `local opts` flag

When you use git flow in install the script locally on your machine.
If you are on unix it depends on the flavor and how you installed it, if you are on windows it should be under your relevant program files\git folder.

Edit the file and remark the `local opts` or remove the `-a` and leave it empty

Comment: I found the file [/usr/lib/git-core/git-flow-release](http://pastebin.com/HUQnZL2h). I edited the file [like this](http://pastebin.com/EmPnzgF0), and it seems to have worked. I'm using `git-flow` version "1.8.0-1" from debian jessie/main.

Comment: I was hoping there was a simpler answer, but looking at the source there doesn't seem to be a way to override the options... :(

Comment: You can add this option, its an open source project